# ActionScript / Flash - Loading External, Programatically Created SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, load, flash, external

i've never had to do any cross scripting until now and i'm running into a (probably really stupid) error right at the start.

**External SWF:**
i've created a new ActionScript 3.0 project in Flash Professional CS5.  on the first frame i've added the following script:

```
//Square.fla frame script

import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;

var s:Shape = new Shape();
s.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 1.0);
s.graphics.drawRect(-100, -100, 200, 200);
s.graphics.endFill();

s.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
s.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

addChild(s);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventHandler);

function enterFrameEventHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    s.rotation += 2;
}
```

save, compile, done.  this works fine as a stand alone swf, which simply displays a rotating blue square at center stage.

**Main SWF:**
i've created a new ActionScript 3.0 file in Flash Professional CS5, which has a document class called *CrossScriptTest*:

```
//CrossScriptTest.as

package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.Sprite
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

//Class
[SWF(width = "1000", height = "500", backgroundColor = "0x444444")]
public class CrossScriptTest extends Sprite
{
    //Constants
    private static const SQUARE_SWF_URL:String = "Square.swf";

    //Variables
    private var SWFLoader:Loader;

    //Constructor
    public function CrossScriptTest()
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.frameRate = 60;

        init();
    }

    //Initialize
    private function init():void
    {
        SWFLoader = new Loader();
        SWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOErrorEventHandler);
        SWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteEventHandler);
        SWFLoader.load(new URLRequest(SQUARE_SWF_URL));
    }

    //IOError Event Handler
    private function IOErrorEventHandler(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        trace(evt);
    }

    //Loader Complete Event Handler
    private function loaderCompleteEventHandler(evt:Event):void
    {
        evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOErrorEventHandler);
        evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteEventHandler);

        var squareSWF:Sprite = Sprite(evt.currentTarget.content);
        addChild(squareSWF);
    }
}
}
```

**Error:**
i receive the following error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at Square_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

perhaps i'm misunderstanding the nature of cross scripting or loading external swf files, but i can only seem to make this work if i've manually drawn display objects on the stage and not if the external swf's display objects are generated by code.

is it not possible to load external swfs that are programatically created and add them to the display list of a main swf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is always so obvious after the fact.  the solution is, of course, to assign an `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event listener in the constructor or initialize method of the external swf's document class.

in my defense this was overlooked since it is not required nor common when creating a standard (internal?) document class.

**Main SWF's Document Class:**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;

    //Class
    [SWF(width = "1000", height = "500", backgroundColor = "0x444444")]
    public class CrossScriptTest extends Sprite
    {
        //Constants
        private static const SQUARE_SWF_URL:String = "Square.swf";

        //Variables
        private var swfLoader:Loader;

        //Constructor
        public function CrossScriptTest()
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.frameRate = 60;

            init();
        }

        //Initialize
        private function init():void
        {
            swfLoader = new Loader();
            swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOErrorEventHandler);
            swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteEventHandler);
            swfLoader.load(new URLRequest(SQUARE_SWF_URL));
        }

        //IOError Event Handler
        private function IOErrorEventHandler(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace(evt);
        }

        //Loader Complete Event Handler
        private function loaderCompleteEventHandler(evt:Event):void
        {
            evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOErrorEventHandler);
            evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteEventHandler);

            addChild(evt.currentTarget.content);
        }
    }
}
```

**External SWF's Document Class:**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.Event;

    //Class
    public class Square extends Sprite
    {
        //Constructor
        public function Square()
        {
            init();
        }

        //Initialize
        private function init():void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageEventHandler);
        }

        //Added To Stage Event Handler
        private function addedToStageEventHandler(evt:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageEventHandler);

            var s:Shape = new Shape();
            s.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 1.0);
            s.graphics.drawRect(-100, -100, 200, 200);
            s.graphics.endFill();

            s.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            s.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

            addChild(s);

            s.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventHandler);
        }

        //Enter Frame Event Handler
        function enterFrameEventHandler(evt:Event):void
        {
            Shape(evt.currentTarget).rotation += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, the stage  property of a DisplayObject is null until that DisplayObject is added to the DisplayList.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, but the way you are doing it doesn't seem right. You could simply use a loader:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("complete", loader_complete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("yourfile.swf"));

function loader_complete(event:*):void {
    var loadedObject:* = event.target;
    // Access the properties of the loaded SWF here
}
```

**Edit:**

In general, try not to use frame scripts, especially when loading SWFs within SWFs, because the way they work is not always obvious. For instance, I don't know what the root is in your script - is it the root of your SWF or that of the parent SWF? (I don't know because, to avoid this kind of problem, I never use frame scripts). To avoid that, you can simply use a document class and put all your code in there.

Maybe try something like that and see if it works:

```
package some.unique.path {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class YourClass extends MovieClip {

        public function YourClass():void {
            var s:Shape = new Shape();
            s.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 1.0);
            s.graphics.drawRect(-100, -100, 200, 200);
            s.graphics.endFill();

            s.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            s.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

            addChild(s);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventHandler);
        }

        function enterFrameEventHandler(evt:Event):void
        {
            s.rotation += 2;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't realize that the code box was scrolling that I didn't see the loading code. Did you turn debug mode on your project? That would tell you on which line exactly the error is happening.

Comment: debug mode doesn't help since i'm loading a swf that is generated from a frame script.  it simply says "Cannot display source code at this location." and the error is the same.

Comment: I have updated my post. Also debug should also work on the child SWF - just turn it on when you compile both SWFs. Flash should add the debug info to them and you should get better error messages.

Comment: i typically do avoid (at all costs) frame scripting.  using frame scripts here was simply a quick, failed test.  however, i have also tried creating a document class but the same error persists:  `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference`, this time locating the error in my `init()` function, or what would simply be your constructor.  have you had luck with this approach using the above code?

Comment: That's strange, your init() code basically looks right and I can't see how anything could be undefined there. I'm just wondering: did you try renaming your variable "SWFLoader" to something else? `SWFLoader` is a Flex class name so that might confuses the compiler.

Comment: figured it out.  i had to add an `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event listener.